# Multiple Columns and Rows in Bootstrap Table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am looking to achieve table something like this in bootstrap 5.

[image]

I have tried like this

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Domain</span></th>
            <th colspan="3"><span>DATE</span></th>
            <th colspan="3"><span>DATE</span></th>
            <th colspan="3"><span>DATE</span></th>
            <th colspan="3"><span>DATE</span></th>
            <th colspan="3"><span>DATE</span></th>
            <th colspan="3"><span>DATE</span></th>
            <th colspan="3"><span>DATE</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Example1</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Example2</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>DR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>IR</span></td >
            <td  rowspan="3" ><span>SR</span></td >
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I am getting weird result like this image

[image]

I am not getting idea what I am missing, searched lot but not found any proper solution for the same. Let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `rowspan` on the DOMAIN, and a second `tr` in the header.
Also you shouldn't have `colspan`s for the subsequent `td`s:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" class="align-middle"><span>Domain</span></th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center"><span>DATE</span></th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center"><span>DATE</span></th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center"><span>DATE</span></th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center"><span>DATE</span></th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center"><span>DATE</span></th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center"><span>DATE</span></th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center"><span>DATE</span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>DR</span></th>
                <th><span>IR</span></th>
                <th><span>SR</span></th>
                <th><span>DR</span></th>
                <th><span>IR</span></th>
                <th><span>SR</span></th>
                <th><span>DR</span></th>
                <th><span>IR</span></th>
                <th><span>SR</span></th>
                <th><span>DR</span></th>
                <th><span>IR</span></th>
                <th><span>SR</span></th>
                <th><span>DR</span></th>
                <th><span>IR</span></th>
                <th><span>SR</span></th>
                <th><span>DR</span></th>
                <th><span>IR</span></th>
                <th><span>SR</span></th>
                <th><span>DR</span></th>
                <th><span>IR</span></th>
                <th><span>SR</span></th>
           
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td><span>Example1</span></td >
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span>Example2</span></td >
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
                <td><span>DR</span></td>
                <td><span>IR</span></td>
                <td><span>SR</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```